# SharePoint bundled with Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2007, share

I was told Windows Server 2008 R2 was bundled with SharePoint. Is this true? I haven't been able to find the feature anywhere in the Server Roles/Features interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "budnled" in taht you do not have to pa for it. It is not bundled in that you have to download the free version separately. The current version is on http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=49c79a8a-4612-4e7d-a0b4-3bb429b46595&displaylang=en (Sharepoint 2010 Foundation)

Answer (score 0):

Windows [Small Business Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sbs/en/us/compare-features.aspx) comes with Exchange 2007 and Sharepoint Services 3.0. I have never heard of it coming bundled with any other OS.

That said, I recently reviewed the minimum system requirements for Sharepoint 2010 and nearly had a heart attack, so tread carefully if you're going to go to 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It is not bundled. You must download it separately, specifically Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SP1 or higher. Documentation on that [here (TechNet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287748(office.12).aspx).